# Filter products array by colors and size

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have an array of products.
One of the products is structured like this:

```
[ {
    sizes: [
    {
      size: 'S',
      colors: [
        {color: 'gray', stock: 10},
        {color: 'black', stock: 0}
      ],
    },
    {
      size: 'L',
      colors: [
        {color: 'black', stock: 5},
        {color: 'red', stock: 0}
      ]
    }
  ],
 ...//other info
 },
//other products
```

]
I also have two states:

```
const [colors, setColors] = useState([])
const [sizes, setSizes] = useState([])
```

So when a user is filtering  by sizes and colors they have selected, I would like to filter the products array accordingly.

Comment: If it is a object you can try with the build fuction filter, let filter = json.products.filter( prod =>  prod.colors.color = "gray" &   prod.colors.stock >= 5 ). Same with a Array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have used here HOF for syntax sugaring:

```
let shirts = {
  sizes: [
    {
      size: "S",
      colors: [
        { color: "gray", stock: 10 },
        { color: "black", stock: 0 }
      ]
    },
    {
      size: "L",
      colors: [
        { color: "black", stock: 5 },
        { color: "red", stock: 0 }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

function bySizes(wantedSizes) {
  return (shirt) => {
    let toKeep = false;
    wantedSizes.forEach((wantedSize) => {
      if (shirt.size.toLowerCase() === wantedSize.toLowerCase()) toKeep = true;
    });
    return toKeep;
  };
}

function byColors(wantedColors) {
  return (shirt) => {
    let toKeep = false;
    shirt.colors.forEach((color) => {
      wantedColors.forEach((wantedColor) => {
        if (color.color === wantedColor) toKeep = true;
      });
    });
    return toKeep;
  };
}

let filteredShirts = shirts.sizes
.filter(bySizes(["S", "XS"]))
.filter(byColors(["black", "white"]))

console.log(filteredShirts);
```

Comment: I don't know if i mentioned it, but the "shirts" should be an array, so its not only one object

Comment: No problem. My point was the usage of HOF. You can implement it any way you see fit, if at all.

Answer (score 0):

You may try useEffect. Here is the example if the user selects the color

```
useEffect(() => {
  const p = products.filter((product) => {return product.color == color});
  setProducts([...p]);
}, [color])
```